# How to optimally configure php-fpm?

Tags: php, configuration, php-fpm

I am using php-fpm along with nginx to server a busy drupal sites. I have not tweaked php5-fpm.conf yet. The stability is fantastic, however, I am wondering how to optimally set the parameters to optimize the performance too. [Here](http://gerardmcgarry.com/blog/how-install-php-fpm-nginx-ubuntu-1004-server) is a set of suggestions:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 8
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 500
```

Any recommendations/comments are very welcomed.

Comment: in my server pm.max_children defaults to 10, Im considering raising it but I haven't found guidelines on how to set the pm.* values